# Xamarin Forms Deployment failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on Xamarin Forms application in Visual studio 2017 .I wanted to deploy application to android simulator .I try to deploy it debug mode.

i set android project as the startup project

When i deploying i get this warning

**No Address and User has been specified in order to establish a connection to a Mac Server, so only the main assembly was compiled for project CMI.IOSApp. Connect to a Mac Server and try again to build the full application.**

Comment: You are trying to build the iOS project, set your active/startup project in the solution to your `Xamarin.Android` application project and start a build/debug session

Comment: Unload your iOS (and UWP) project(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to VS menu `Build->Configuration Manager` is iOS project tick when you have set your android project as start up project.
So the Build and Deploy checkbox for iOS project should be untick when you are going for Android build.